# questions about how to show sequence of functions are uniform convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

There is a theorem :

Assume that

(1) $\{f_n\}$ sequence of functions in $A$ point-wise converge to $f$

(2) for any $n$, $\{f_n\}$ is of class $C^1$ function

(3) $\{f_n'\}$ converge uniformly to $g$.

Then :

(1) $f$ is differentiable.

(2) $f'(x)=g(x)$.

I don't quit understand this theorem, does it mean to take derivative when checking if the sequence function is uniformly convergent? or we take a limit as $n$ goes to infinity, and check if the function go to a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem is just saying this: Suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $f'_n \rightarrow g$ uniformly.  Then $f$ must be nice enough that we can take its derivative, and we also have $$\frac{d}{dx} f = \frac{d}{dx} \lim f_n = \lim \frac{d}{dx} f_n = g.$$

In other words, we can swap the order of taking limits and taking derivatives whenever the derivatives converge uniformly to something ($g$ in this case).

Comment: but how would you check if a sequence function is uniformly convergent?

Comment: In general, there's not a convenient test. As far as I know, you just have to compute the limiting function and see if the definition of uniform convergence applies.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

We know that if a series of functions $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to some function $f$, then it also converges $\textit{pointwise}$ to that function. A good place to start when trying to calculate uniform limits of functions is to first compute the pointwise limit, then try to prove uniform convergence to that limit.

This theorem does not necessarily mean you should take the derivative to figure out if a function is uniformly convergent. This theorem says that if a series of functions $\{f_n\}$ as well as the series of its derivatives $\{f'_n\}$ converges uniformly, then $f$ is differentiable.

Checking if a function "goes to a constant" as you asked, is not very relevant here, because the uniform limit of a series of functions (or a series of derivatives of functions) is $\textit{not}$ necessarily always a constant. For example, the uniform limit of $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1n}$ on $[0,10]$ is $f(x) = |x|$, which is clearly not constant on this domain.

Comment: do we just treat X as a constant when computing the limit as n goes to infinity? and when X is in a given interval, do we just need to check each endpoint? or just use our common sense to check the function itself, and see if there is any point that is not convergent?

Comment: 1. Compute the limit as n goes to infinity for fixed x (I think this is what you mean by "treat x as a constant.") 
2. If for some x in the given domain, the sequence of functions does not converge, then the sequence does not converge on that domain. So yes, you should be careful about the endpoints.

Comment: is it ok if you set the x equal to n ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what purpose that would achieve. For the function I defined above, to calculate the pointwise limit (and thus candidate for a uniform limit), fix an arbitrary x in [0,10] and let n go to positive infinity. You cannot use x and n interchangeably.

Comment: sorry, my question was not about the example above, im just asking for general. for example: fn(x)=(nx)/(1+n^2+x^2) can u set x equal to n, so that the function is not uniform convergent?

Comment: I'm still confused by your question. You cannot use x and n interchangeably. I don't see the purpose of doing this in general, either. Once again, going back to my example, if you "set x equal to n," the function becomes squareroot(n^2 + 1/n), which goes to infinity as n goes to infinity. Setting x equal to n in this fashion doesn't gain you any traction in proving or disproving uniform convergence in this case.

Comment: fn(x)=(nx)/(1+n^2+x^2) for this sequence function, it is not uniform convergent because when x=n, the function's limit is 1/2, and for other values of x, the function goes to 0. i was asking if we could set x=n or not.